# Stripping out html tags in string

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace

I have a program I'm writing that is *supposed* to strip html tags out of a string. I've been trying to replace all strings that start with "<" and end with ">". This (obviously because I'm here asking this) has not worked so far. Here's what I've tried:

```
StrippedContent = Regex.Replace(StrippedContent, "\<.*\>", "")
```

That just returns what seems like a random part of the original string. I've also tried

```
For Each StringMatch As Match In Regex.Matches(StrippedContent, "\<.*\>")
    StrippedContent = StrippedContent.Replace(StringMatch.Value, "")
Next
```

Which did the same thing (returns what seems like a random part of the original string). Is there a better way to do this? By better I mean a way that works.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- find and replace all tags with nothing
- avoid problematic edge cases

Regex: `<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`

Replace with:  nothing

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the difficult edge case in the mouse over function

`these are <a onmouseover=' href="NotYourHref" ; if (6/a>3) { funRotator(href) } ; ' href=abc.aspx?filter=3&prefix=&num=11&suffix=>the droids</a> you are looking for.`

**Code**

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim replacementstring as String = ""
    Dim matchpattern as String = "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>"
    Console.Writeline(regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementstring,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline))
  End Sub
End Module
```

**String after replacement**

```
these are the droids you are looking for.
```

Comment: Really the best regex to this topic I've seen so far! +1

Comment: using this answer, how does one try to avoid the <br> tags, so that the breaks do appear? i have a document with many breaks, so when the above answer is used, the text comes back as one large paragraph

Comment: @NicholasAysen I assume you're looking to replace all the HTML tags except the `<br>` tags? If so then you'd just add a negative forward look ahead like `<(?!br)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>` [see also this link](http://www.rubular.com/r/kUAAwKIriY), cheers.

Comment: @Denomales thanks very much. i also saw that, upon further looks into the data i pull, there were some tags with double << and  >>. so i just replaced all those with single tags, and didn't have to change anything else. but i will def keep this for the future thanks

Comment: There are few assumptions here about the input. At least: tags should not have newlines inside the tag, and there should be no spaces around `=` between attribute name and attribute value (e.g., `<p id = ">">` fails).

Comment: Heads up: It will strip out a `<style>` tag but not the contents.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this proves that you should always search Google for an answer. Here's a method I got from http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags-vbnet

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim html As String = "<p>There was a <b>.NET</b> programmer " +
          "and he stripped the <i>HTML</i> tags.</p>"
        Dim tagless As String = StripTags(html)
        Console.WriteLine(tagless)
    End Sub
    Function StripTags(ByVal html As String) As String
        Return Regex.Replace(html, "<.*?>", "")
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: This solution will have problems if any of your markup contains  attributes like: `some text<a onmouseover="if ( 6 > x ) { funDoSomething ; } ">more text`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function using the regex pattern that Ro Yo Mi posted.

```
<Extension()> Public Function RemoveHtmlTags(value As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(value, "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>", "")
End Function
```

Demonstration:

```
Dim html As String = "This <i>is</i> just a <b>demo</b>.".RemoveHtmlTags()
Console.WriteLine(html)
```