# Remove HTML tags from string using regex, without removing '<' characters from actual text between tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, tags

I know a lot of people have been asking how to remove HTML tags from strings by regex, but I can't immediately find exactly what I am looking for.

The closest answer I found to what I am looking for was the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668453/8417376, which advises to use `<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>` as regex pattern.

Unfortunately, this does not work when you have the following example: `<p>value < other value </p>` (In this case, `< other value </p>` is seen as a HTML tag)

Is there anyone with a good solution?

Thanks in advance!

PS: If there is a better way of doing this in C#, please don't hesitate to let me know! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<(?:[^><=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>
```